# How do I omit several patterns with a single ls command (in zsh)?

Tags: zsh, ls

I use latex often, and would like to create an ls alias that excludes all the extra files produced by pdflatex with the exception of .tex and .pdf. Using a single pattern with the "^" option works, but if I put in several patterns, it runs each one as an individual command, with the result that the files that don't match each pattern are listed multiple times.

Is there any way to omit several patterns at once with a single command in zsh?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `KSH_GLOB` is enabled.

```
% setopt KSH_GLOB
% touch foo.{tex,aux,log,pdf}    
% ls foo.!(aux|pdf)
foo.pdf foo.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group patterns with `(...|...)` and negate grouped patterns with `^`, the last of which requires `EXTENDED_GLOB` to be set. For example:

```
ls ^*.(aux|log)
```

This will match anything but files with names matching `*.aux` or `*.log`. More exclusion patterns can be chained with additional `|`:

```
ls ^*.(aux|log|toc|dvi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just

`ls --hide=*.aux --hide=*.log`

But remember, this expression matching is not regex. It is globbing.

Comment: Not all versions of `ls` support `--hide`.